# How to cast ICaptureDevice as WinPcapDevice

Tags: c#, .net, sharppcap

I'm looking at the [SharpPcap tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12458/SharpPcap-A-Packet-Capture-Framework-for-NET) and am trying to understand how to access the *device* details, which from this post: [In SharpPCap How do I find the IP Address of the Device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996596/in-sharppcap-how-do-i-find-the-ip-address-of-the-device) indicates that I must cast the `ICaptureDevice` object into a specific type such as `WinPcapDevice`.

They show how to iterate over the device list, but not how to do the type cast:

```
// Retrieve all capture devices
var devices = CaptureDeviceList.Instance;

// differentiate based upon types
foreach (ICaptureDevice dev in devices)
{
  if (dev is AirPcapDevice)
  {
    // process as an AirPcapDevice
  }
  else if(dev is WinPcapDevice)
  {
    // process as an WinPcapDevice
  }
  else if(dev is LibPcapLiveDevice)
  {
    // process as an LibPcapLiveDevice
  }
}
```

Comment: `var winPcap = (WinPcapDevice)dev;`

Comment: Thanks Lee, I knew it was going to be something simple like that!

Comment: I Think that you can place your comment as answser, Lee.